# Google Cloud - Datastore is too slow compared to local machine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We are using Google App Engine with Datastore and Objectify. In our local machine it's taking 1 second to do a query while in the cloud it's taking arround 20 seconds. The server location is in europe-west and I am in Spain so I don't think this is the issue.

The query we are performing is just retrieving data with just 1 filter:

```
final CityEntity cityEntity = new CityEntity();
cityEntity.setId(1);
ofy().load().type(Person.class).filter("city =", cityEntity).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the datastore, queries scale with the size of the result set. How many people are in the city? If large, the query will not only be slow, you'll quickly hit the limits of RAM.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may need to take a different approach. For example, you could perform a keys-only query, convert the result to tasks, and enqueue a task for each person. That will probably work up to hundreds of thousands, maybe low millions before you hit the 10m deadline of a task/cron. For larger quantities, you probably want some form of map/reduce.

Comment: it's filtering by one field into an entity with up to 2000 records. Is it normal to take 20 seconds then? I find it a bit excesive

Comment: That does seem a bit slow. I would normally expect about 1000/s from the old-style appengeine API, although the new REST API is a bit slower. It could depend on a lot of different things. Remember that the datastore is designed to work across massive scale, so you could do hundreds of thousands of operations per second across the whole system, but any individual operation is not particularly fast.