# GAE Datastore - Objectify Read Performance

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm more used to SQL databases than Google DataStore, but I'm finding that my read performance is much slower than I expected. I just want to check if either I've structured my data incorrectly, or if my performance expectations are unreasonable.

I have a DataStore entity called assessment, and on that entity I have added a property Client. This is modelling a master-detail relationship where client is the master and assessment is the detail.

In the GCP console, my entity looks like this : [image]

There are 112 occurrences of this entity, and to query this entity by client takes just under 3 seconds.

I use Objectify to retrieve the data, with the following statement :

```
List<Assessment> assessments = ofy().load()
                                 .type(Assessment.class)
                                 .filter("client = ", Key.create(Client.class, clientId))
                                 .list();
```

Coming from an SQL background, 3 seconds to read from 112 a row table via an index seems unreasonably slow to me. Are my expectations of DataStore wrong, or am I doing something stupid in either the way I've chosen to store the data, or the way that I'm reading it?

Comment: This might be related to your concern: [Google cloud datastore slow (>800ms) with simple query from compute engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454958/google-cloud-datastore-slow-800ms-with-simple-query-from-compute-engine/40684933#40684933) and [Google Cloud - Datastore is too slow compared to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077218/google-cloud-datastore-is-too-slow-compared-to-local-machine).

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya : thanks for your comments, but it seems to be the VPN that is crippling my local desktop performance. I disconnected from that, and we're back to a very quick response time again. ( That's two days of research and a couple of sleepless nights I'm not getting back! )

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this here in case another poor soul comes along ....

It seems the problem was my NordLayer VPN

Log out of that and the response time falls to 68 milliseconds!